# What Happens If I Hard Reset(30-30-30) Router in DD Firmware?

Tags: dd-wrt

What will happen if I hard reset router with DD-WRT in it. Will it factory reset to DD-WRT or revert back to its original firmware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will just reset DD-WRT back to the defaults.

From the [DD-WRT Wiki](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hard_reset_or_30/30/30):

> Hard Reset... will clear out the NVRAM and set dd-wrt back to default
>   values

Answer (score 0):

It will reset back to the latest firmware that you have flashed.

This reset wipes the partitions that hold any configuration you have added.